# How to publishh shared addin in vs2008 to clickonce?

Tags: clickonce

I have a windows application which i am publishing to ClickOnce deployment along with it i am adding a Shared Addin dll and setting the property it as content.
So when i click on ClickOnce applicaiton the .exe and Shared addin dll copies to the directory and using the exe i need to register the dll.
Can it be automated?? How do we publish shared addin as clickonce?
I am using VS2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume from the fact you want to register the dll that we're talking COM. ClickOnce doesn't register dlls, but you don't need to register it if you use registration free COM. Check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188708.aspx) for details on how to do this with ClickOnce.